# C# Entity Framework : How to return a specified type after group.join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two specific types of objects which i'm handling :

**FoodType**
**FoodItem**

**Structure :**
A FoodType has a list of FoodItems  (ft is FoodType and fi is FoodItem) (Entity Framework types))

I want to return an IList based on this LINQ Query :

```
var list = foodTypes.GroupJoin
                (fullList, ft => ft.Id, fi => fi.FoodTypeId, (ft, f) => new {ft, f})
                .Where(g => g.f.Any()).ToList() as IList<FoodType>;
```

**Output looks like this :**

[image]

Know what returntype this actually is ? And.. how can i change this to make it the returntype i want ?

**Complete method :**

```
public static void GetMenuFoodItems2(int menuId)
    {
        using (var context = new MSEntities())
        {
            Menu menu =
                context.Menus.Include("FoodTypes").Include("FoodItems").FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == menuId);

            var singleFoodItems = menu.FoodItems;
            var foodTypeItems = menu.FoodTypes.SelectMany(ft => ft.FoodItems);
            var fullList = singleFoodItems.Union(foodTypeItems).ToList();

            var foodTypes = context.FoodTypes.ToList();

            var list = foodTypes.GroupJoin
                (fullList, ft => ft.Id, fi => fi.FoodTypeId, (ft, f) => new {ft, f})
                .Where(g => g.f.Any()).ToList();

        }
    }
```

**Here is a image of the EDMX :**

[image]

Comment: The result is an anonymous type, `new {ft, f}`. It basically has no official type. You can select something like `new FoodGroup(*whatever*)` instead, but you might just need to rethink what you're trying to do with that query.

Comment: Showing the `FoodType` and `FoodItem` classes would really help. You can't return an `IList` - interfaces aren't object. You can return something like `List` that implements the `IList` interface, but that is what `ToList` does.

Comment: Looking at it, it seems like you are pulling all the `FoodTypes` that are used in `menu`. Do the `singleFoodItems` have a `FoodTypeId` that matches something in `FoodTypes`?

Comment: Added image of the EDMX, to show the relation::

Comment: @NetMage : yes.. All FoodItems belongs to a single FoodType.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of this is an `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>`, with the anonymous type that has two properties - `ft` of type `FoodType`, and `f` of type `IEnumerable<FoodItem>`.

If you want to drop `f` because all you wanted is to see that it is non-empty, add a `Select` that extracts `FoodType` from the pair:

```
var list = foodTypes.GroupJoin
    (fullList, ft => ft.Id, fi => fi.FoodTypeId, (ft, f) => new {ft, f})
    .Where(g => g.f.Any())
    .Select(p => p.ft)
    .ToList();
```

If you want to keep `FoodItem`s along with `FoodType`, make a new class to bind the two together. Do not reuse navigation property `FoodItems`.

```
class FoodTypeItems {
    public FoodType {get;set;}
    public IList<FoodItem> FoodItems {get;set;}
}
...
var list = foodTypes.GroupJoin
    (fullList, ft => ft.Id, fi => fi.FoodTypeId, (ft, f) => FoodTypeItems {
        FoodType = ft
    ,   FoodItems = f.ToList()}
    ).Where(g => g.FoodItems.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The original list is a IList<FoodItem>. and all the "elements" has a specific FoodType connected to it.. 

Wanted result is a IList<FoodType> with it's FoodItems connected to it as IList<FoodItem>...

Comment: @NetMage It's not redundant: [if there are no correlated elements in inner for a given element of outer, the sequence of matches for that element will be empty but will still appear in the results.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @NetMage : A bit over my head unfortunately :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are correct - my test cases weren't complete (though that begs a question about `SelectMany` and left outer join...).

Comment: @TerjeNygård Where do you expect to put the connected `FoodItem`s in a `FoodType`? Is there a field in `FoodType` that is a `IList<FoodItem` already?

Comment: @NetMage : I want to have a IList<FoodType> with it's properties and especially a list of FoodItems connected to it (IList<FoodItem>)..
Relation : A FoodType can have <many> FoodItems...

Comment: What does "connected to it" mean in the C# context of classes and objects?

Comment: It means... All FoodItems has one FoodType connected to it.

Comment: @TerjeNygård The `FoodItem`s connected to a `FoodType` are always connected to it - it looks like a navigation property. Do you want just the `FoodItem`s that are in the `menu`? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @NetMage : the "road" is : A menu can have both FoodTypes and FoodItems  (2 x many-to-many tables).. I have extracted out 2 x lists, and used "union" to bring out all FoodItems... I am trying to "up/reverse" the list to return FoodType instead of FoodItem. So i can use a ListView to show the FoodType, and then.. a nested ListView to show all FoodItem on that FoodType.

Comment: @TerjeNygård Don't reuse `FoodType` for return type of this method, use a different class. It looks like the list of food items that you try to associate to a type is "synthesized" on the fly, so a better approach here would be to use a simple tuple-like class (see edit).

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight : :) I will give this a shot !.. I feared that i had to go through a "viewmodel"'ish  approach to get this to work properly.

Comment: @TerjeNygård When you say "show all `FoodItem` on that `FoodType`", do you mean "show all `FoodItem` _**in the menu**_ that have that `FoodType`"?

Comment: Yes :) 1) Get the Menu with ID=?, -then- get all FoodItems, -then-, "massage" the output and turn it, so it's categorized/grouped by FoodType, not FoodItem. did that make sense ?

Comment: Finally worked out... Through your approach @dasblinkenlight.. 

Here's final code : IList<MenuFoodType> list = foodTypes.GroupJoin
                    (fullList, ft => ft.Id, fi => fi.FoodTypeId, (ft, fi) => new { ft, fi })
                    .Where(g => g.fi.Any()).ToList().Select(n => new MenuFoodType {
                            mFoodType = n.ft,
                            mFoodItems = n.fi.ToList()
                        }).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, it's returning an anonymous type because you're selecting a `new {}` object, not something like a `new FoodType { }`.

But I think the GroupJoin may be over-complicating things.

Just a guess but I feel like this would cover it for you. (Psuedo-code, I forget off the top of my head whether multiple null propagation operators are necessary.)

```
context.Menus
    .Include(m => m.FootTypes)
    .Include(m => m.FootTypes.Select(ft => ft.FoodItems)) // or SelectMany?
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == menuId)
   ?.Select(m => m.FootTypes)
   ?.Where(ft => ft.FoodItems.Any())
   ?.ToList();
```

Comment: I will give this a shot riiiight away :)

Comment: Oh.. just one comment (hmm.. i'm not that expert at linq).. I cannot do a select or where statement on that firstOrDefault...

Comment: oh yeah, I guess it would help to Include.  FirstOrDefault forces a trip to the database (enumerates the IQueryable)